# Problem with getting the scraped data table Python

Tags: python

```sh
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://crypto.com/price'
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")
row = soup.find("tbody")
for x in row :
    a = str(x.text)
    print(a)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yU8S.png)

how does the data that gets scraped would scraped properly

Comment: You can use selenium or if you would like to continue to use BeatifulSoup, you can use regex to modify your output to have in "correct/clear" formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would get you in the ballpark:

```
table_body= soup.find("tbody")

for table_row in table_body :
    for table_column in table_row.findAll():
        for ele in table_column:
            if ele.name == 'div':print(table_column.get_text())
```

That site has a lot happening in the table, but this spits out pretty clean data. Likely there is a lot more you can do here, but at least this gets you values.